# Why does Beautifulsoup's contents method return text with brackets and quotes, whereas the text method returns just plain text

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am scraping company names from a webpage using Python3 and Beautifulsoup. When I use the "contents" method to pull the contents of a tag, it returns the text with brackets and single quotes (e.g. ['Company A']) whereas the "text" method returns simply Company A. Why do the functions behave this way? I realize this may be a dumb question but I'm new and have tried searching around. See Below:

```
 entity_name = bsObj2.find(class_='span-16 first')
 entity_name_item = entity_name.find('h1')
 entity_name_item = entity_name_item.contents
 print(entity_name_item)
```

Returns:

```
['Company A']
```

Whereas:

```
 entity_name = bsObj2.find(class_='span-16 first')
 entity_name_item = entity_name.find('h1')
 entity_name_item = entity_name_item.text
 print(entity_name_item)
```

Returns:

```
 Company A
```

Comment: To get the expected behavior, try changing `.contents` to `.contents[0]` because `.contents` returns an array of items or list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`contents` gives you a list with the tag childrens, while `text` gives you the text of a tag.

Answer (score 0):

`contents` returns all the results of a find as a Python `list`, while `text` gives you the text value of what was found as a Python `string`. For instance, in the following HTML:

```
<div>Header
<h1>Header2</h1>
</div>
```

Parsing it with Beautiful Soup and calling `result = soup.find('div')` returns a `BeautifulSoup` object. Calling `contents` on that object returns the list of that tag and all its children, i.e. `result.contents == ['Header', 'Header2']` and `type(result)` returns `<class 'list'>`. But `text` returns things in a human readable format as a string, so you get something like `result.text == 'Header Header2` and `type(result)` gets you `<class 'string'>`.